# how to use Google Sheet Scripts to warn when approaching size limit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am using a Google Form to receive survey responses. However, I had not realized that there are [limits](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2505921?hl=en) to how many responses you can gather (limited to 400,000 cells per sheet).

I am getting a lot more responses than I anticipated, and will be hitting the limits more quickly than I'd anticipated.

I would like to add some scripting (or something else) to the sheet to send me an email when I'm approaching the limit. I have never used Google Sheet Scripts before.

Is this possible?

Comment: The new style spreadsheet is bigger, will it work? ... Regards the question: google-apps-script will measure sheet size and send email. Suggest you re-tag the question.

Comment: Hi. I fear it may still not be good enough. I retagged question. Thanks. No suggestions yourself on how to script that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. First use new sheets. If still not enough you may specify no spreadsheet for responses. If so the forms will keep data internally which is also more efficient and avoids size limitations.
When done, download responses directly as csv. see here: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/139706?hl=en

about warning the user, you cant. There are many variables involved not just the 400,000 cell limit (and are all different on the new sheets.)

Comment: say I just wanted to check the 400,000 cell limit? Also, I can't seem to find newer values.

Comment: just do sheet.getLastRow()*numColumns (getLastColumn), assuming your data is in that sheet. Not sure what you mean about finding newer values

Comment: the increased limits you make reference to